# C# - Form opacity is always 100%

Tags: c#, forms, opacity

For some reason, my form is always at 100% opacity.  I've tried changing it by using the properties window.  For example, I changed it to 40% but when I ran the program, it is 100%.  Are there any known reasons for this?  I've looked throughout my entire code and nothing is changing it to 100%.  Thanks.

Comment: are you doing anything in the constructor, on load, or shown events? What if you create a brand new form in the same project, does it do the same thing?

Comment: Nothing that would interfere with the opacity.  And yes, I made another form and it works for that one.  I'm so confused.

Comment: Do you have an ActiveX control displayed on the form, or some other external component?

Comment: What *is* on the form? I expect this is going to be hard to look at without a repeatable example.

Comment: A menustrip, some buttons, labels, groupboxes, textboxes, a combobox and a numericupdown.

Comment: Long shot, but you're not using RightToLeftLayout are you?

Comment: Nope, I can't figure this out at all...

Comment: Another long shot: you're setting the Opacity to 0.4, not to 40, right?  Sorry for asking such a dumb question, but just in case.

Comment: No, but I just closed and re-opened the project and now it's working....weird.  Thanks for your time and help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason when I closed and re-opened the project, it started working.  No idea why that is.